# how to update/ repaint jpanel partially (background stuff is not painted again.it remains there as it is)

Tags: java, swing

We are developing Graphics based application where we need to call repaint method again and again. Now repaint method repaints the whole screen but we want it to repaint only a portion of the Screen keeping reamaining part painted. Is it possible ? if yes then how ?

Comment: In the current form I do not understand your question. Can you please explain what you are looking for? And try to prepare an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2):

you can try overloaded forms of `repaint()` method e.g. [repaint to specific rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29)

Comment: Please link to the latest docs.  +1 for the concept.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if I understood you correct, but first thing I though of was overriding the paint() method in your JPanel. If you dont clear the JPanel in this method your are able to draw over the exisiting drawing. However, the logistic of this seems extremely tiresome, and I would rather advise using multiple JPanels and use each of them as entities on a larges JPanel scene. This would allow you to redraw each entity and then combine them into the scene you want.

Comment: *"first thing I though of was overriding the paint() method in your JPanel."*  Please refrain from giving out advice on custom painting in Swing - at least until you know the correct method to override. -1

Comment: I had no idea that overriding the paint() method was considered bad in any way. But please educate me, of refer me to some site where I can learn the correct way.

Comment: As [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) explains, descendants of JComponent should override paintComponent, not paint.  See also [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).  Not that it matters here, since the repaint(Rectangle) answer was the correct one.

Comment: See the [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson of the tutorial.